# How do Cisco switches are supplied with power?

Tags: cisco, switch

I heard from a Cisco Training that Cisco switches don't have a power socket. And I actually searched for Switches' images, and indeed I don't see any.

Does this mean that the switch doesn't need power? if so, how are all features powered up (for example Cisco IOS Operating System)?

[image]

Comment: there's a power socket on the back.

Comment: They do require power, there's a socket on the backside.

Comment: By power socket they might mean something else

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A few selected switches, like [this one](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/products/collateral/switches/slm2008-8-port-gigabit-smart-switch-pd-ac-power/data_sheet_c78-500596.html) can be powered by POE and thus don't use external power supply.

But all other switches (including the one in your photo) do require power and have a regular [C14 power socket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEC_60320#C13.2FC14_coupler) on the backside.

Many Cisco switches can be powered trough a regular C14 power socket (110 / 220V AC) as well as , for redundancy, trough a specific connector connected to a [Redundant Power System](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/switches/power_supplies/rps2300/hardware/installation/guide/2300hig/rpsoview.html)

Some others have dual traditional power supply (hot plug-able)